# Choosing between State by Year Fixed Effects v/s State Specific Linear Time Trends

Tags: regression, panel, stata, economics, longitudinal

I had a random question about fixed effects and I wanted to clarify this with you. Suppose a study is at the individual by state by year level where each individual is followed over time (Panel) and I am adding state fixed effects, year fixed effects as well as state by year fixed effects. Does that mean I might run into multi-collinearity problems? Also will something like this soak up all of the variability and we would not be able to get the correct coefficient estimates?

In Stata I am doing something like reg y x i.year##i.statefip [aw=population], vce(robust)

Or should I rather do something like reg y x i.year i.statefip c.year#i.statefip [aw=population], vce(robust) as in add state specific time trends.

Comment: This question is more a statistics question than a programming question and would be better suited for Cross Validated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a panel dataset, it would be much better for you to *xtset* it first, rather than trying to use the regular *reg* command. If you're using FE with *xtreg*, then first, the state-level fixed effects are automatically generated (and you wouldn't have to mess with the syntax in the OLS -- not sure why you would be using the regular OLS in the first place if you have panel data). Then you can include your time fixed effects with i.year. At the end, just have i.statefip and i.year, because they are both categorical and not continuous. Let me know if you have any more questions.